# How to freeze one dataset in report builder?

Tags: reporting-services

I have two datasets in report builder 2.0. The first datatset is at top with just one row. Second data set has same number of columns but around 100 rows. I succeed with freezing the columns of second dataset when scroll for 100 rows. But i need to freeze the first dataset at the top (just above the second one), so that when i scroll the 100 rows of second dataset, i can see the above table and columns of second dataset all the time.Is there is something in report builder for this?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Punia

Comment: *nudge* How'd you go with this?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240753.aspx) will help you do this. You want to populate a tablix control with your dataset and follow this guide. If you have any questions feel free to reply with this answer with a comment and I'll come back and update my answer.